# Hard drive after PCB swap strange stuff

Tags: hard-drive

I’ve done a PCB swap to my HDD. The HDD model is: WD6400AAKS-00A7B2. 
The original PCB PN matches the new one (first three letter groups), though the cache mismatches (16MB original, 8MB new). The Hardware store that made the swap told me it was hard to do the swap, they have done firmware adaptation. I can see that this firmware version does not match the original, (01.03B01 original, 05.04E05 new). 
Still I can see that the serial number and model of the drive is correct, the hard drive appeared normal in the BIOS, all the partitions show and everything appears normal.

I have encountered three things though, I have left the drive non operated for 2-3 weeks after the swap to avoid corrupting the data or anything else the new PCB might cause, until I buy a new drive and backup the data. I got a drive, and when I powered the old drive manually (I have a laptop, I use a normal desktop power supply and a USB/SATA connector), I heard the motor start and I could hear ticking as if the motor’s somehow struggling to start, and then the motor sound starts again then the ticking, and so on.. I tried powering again it happened again. The third time it started normally and I could see everything normally. I took the chance and copied all the data over to the new drive. 
When I was done, I powered off the drive (after more than 25 hours of continuous operation), tried to power it up again and it did so normally, and so are the times I powered it up later; but I got very suspicious now. What could be the problem here? And what happened new, it used to power normally after the swap directly?

The second thing that happened is that I found size differences with some files; some include movies, songs, (.iso) files for games, and programs. I could find the size is the same, but size on disk is a little more on the new drive for these files. . I’ve tried some of those files (with size differences) they worked fine. They are not too much but still make you suspicious of the integrity of the data copied; one cannot try if all files are working for about (580 GB) worth of data. I tried copying these files on the same partition they exist of the old drive; they are the same in size as when copied to the new drive (allocation unit size not the issue). I took an image of a partition (sector by sector including empty ones) and when I explore it, these file sizes are equal to the original (old drive); I copy them anywhere else their size on disk, increases, i.e becomes equal to the ones I copy from the old drive itself anywhere.
Why the size difference and can one trust the integrity of the data??

The third thing is that when I connect my new external USB HDD, the partitions of the old HDD unmount and then mount again. Connected are: (USB mouse + Old HDD) then external HDD. Why that happens??

Considering the following:
I compared the SMART reports from after the swap directly and after the copying, no error readings or reallocated sectors where reported. Here they are: http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-1939-219.html

I later ran both WD data life guard tests and they came out passed.

I’m worried for this drive since I must be sure the data is fine and safe on the new one, and I will consider it backup for the new one, since you can’t trust anything anymore.
I hope you can forgive me for the length of the post, but couldn’t ignore any of the details, this hard drive contains very important data to me and I have to deal with the situation with great care.

Comment: Your hdd is failing.  The fact you had to replace PCB means you need to just replace the entire hdd.  Your question is all over the place.  **I suggest you have somebody proof read it because your thoughts are all over the place.**  For instance you don't even tell us what the sector size is on the new hdd.  The files are likely actually the same size.

Comment: "Your question is all over the place. I suggest you have somebody proof read it because your thoughts are all over the place." Please explain further I don't get what you mean. I copied the files on the same partition where they used to be on the old drive their size on disk changes to be equal to that when copied on the new drive. the bytes per sector on the new drive is 4kb.

Comment: Its hard to follow what actually happen.  I am trying to allow you to clarify your question so you can be helped.

Comment: 1- For 3 weeks after the replacement of the PCB I left the drive not powered. After that when I tried to power it it made the sound I described instead of powering up normally. 2- When I copy some files in particular from the old drive anywhere including on the same partition where the file came from, the size on disk increases. 3- when I connect my external drive (USB) the old drive's partitions unmount, and then mount again (the autorun screen appears) when the old drive is connected through USB as well. I hope I made it clearer and if u need anymore details plz ask.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you answered your own question

"I’ve done a PCB swap to my HDD. The HDD model is: WD6400AAKS-00A7B2. The original PCB PN matches the new one (first three letter groups), though the **cache mismatches** (16MB original, 8MB new). The Hardware store that made the swap told me it was hard to do the swap, they have done firmware adaptation. I can see that this **firmware version does not match the original**, (01.03B01 original, 05.04E05 new). Still I can see that the serial number and model of the drive is correct, the hard drive appeared normal in the BIOS, all the partitions show and everything appears normal."

You did not replace the PCB with an *identical* copy. This will lead to numerous issues. Mainly since the PCB you swapped to has a smaller cache size is likely it was meant to handle a different drive motor than the model installed or the acceleration curve for the drive motor is different with the new firmware.

if you can get that data you need off do so as soon as possible and dont use that drive any more.